# Show that the group $(\Bbb Z,+)$ cannot be expressed as an internal direct product of two non-trivial subgroups

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Show that the group $(\Bbb Z,+)$ cannot be expressed as an internal direct product  of two non-trivial subgroups.

My solution goes like this:

> Any non-trivial subgroups of $(\Bbb Z,+)$ is of the form $n\Bbb Z$, $n\neq 0,1$. Let $h\Bbb Z,k\Bbb Z$ be two such non-trivial subgroups of $\Bbb Z$, where $h,k\in\Bbb Z$. So, $h\Bbb Z k\Bbb Z=\{hakb,\forall a,b\in\Bbb Z\}.$ Now, $\exists g\in\Bbb Z$, such that $\gcd(g,hk)=1$. Hence, $g\notin k\Bbb Z h\Bbb Z$. Hence, $\Bbb Z\neq k\Bbb Z h\Bbb Z$, where $k\Bbb Z, h\Bbb Z$ were arbitary non-trivial subgroup. Thus, *$(\Bbb Z,+)$ cannot be expressed as an internal direct product  of two non-trivial subgroups.*

Is the above solution correct? If not, where is it going wrong?

Comment: @hawaiianearringgroup No, I think that can never be the case as I mentioned in my post if $g=h=k=1$, then, $g\Bbb Z,h\Bbb Z$, becomes trivial subgroups. That's why I mentioned $n\neq 0,1$.

Comment: No, $1\Bbb Z=Z.$

Comment: @hawaiianearringgroup Yeah, and $1\Bbb Z$, is trivial. It's given in the question **internal direct product of two non-trivial subgroups**. That's what I am talking about?!

Comment: Oh OK.  Didn't see that.

Comment: @hawaiianearringgroup No problem, friend

Comment: The name "Trivial subgroup" is by many reserved for the single-element subgroup only. That's why the stock phrase "_proper_, nontrivial subgroup" is popular. I'm not really saying you're wrong to use "trivial subgroup" to refer to both the whole group and the singleton subgroup, but I do think you are wrong to expect everyone else to implicitly understand that you mean it that way.

Comment: @Arthur Yeah, that's right...

Comment: @Arthur But is my proof correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing sums with products. Doing $h\mathbb{Z}k\mathbb{Z}$ is not the way and is meaningless in this context.

Since the operation is $+$, the condition for being a direct product of two subgroups would be
$$
\mathbb{Z}=H+K,\quad H\cap K=\{0\}
$$
where $H+K=\{a+b:a\in H,b\in K\}$.

Now, suppose $h\ge 0$ and $k\ge 0$. Can you have
$$
h\mathbb{Z}\cap k\mathbb{Z}=\{0\}
$$
without one among $h$ and $k$ being zero?

Comment: But how to prove $h\Bbb Z\cap k\Bbb Z\neq {0}$? Can we prove it like this that:$hk=kh\neq 0$ and $hk\in h\Bbb Z\cap k\Bbb Z$ as $h,k\neq 0$ as it is given the subgroups **must be non-trivial** ?

Comment: @Franklin You surely know that $hk\in h\mathbb{Z}\cap k\mathbb{Z}$, don't you? If either is nonzero…

Comment: yeah so the proof I wrote after editing my prev comment completes the proof, correct?

Comment: @Franklin Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thank you so much!